# Excel: Highlight row that has max and min values in other columns

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, maxifs

I have a simple Excel table that I want to highlight the row that has max in columns A,B, D and min in C. In this example it should highlight row 1

```
    A       B       C       D
1   36.4%   35.9%   2.25    272.8
2   19.4%   9.0%    6.5     122
3   17.5%   20.2%   3.2     248.5
4   6.4%    11.9%   16      137.3
5   2.7%    9.8%    23      108.2
```

All criteria must match, so if the max in one column is not on the same row as the max in the other column etc.., then it's not a match, hence it's possible no row is highlighted. I've tried max, maxifs, large but not having any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do CF rule based on formula:

`=AND(MAX($A$1:$A$5)=$A1;MAX($B$1:$B$5)=$B1;MAX($D$1:$D$5)=$D1;MIN($C$1:$C$5)=$C1)`

[image]

[image]